# UWP TextBlock does not update when bound to function

Tags: mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

We are using UWP with Template10. `Template10.ViewModelBase` manages change notification. We have a `CostTextBlock` bound to `ViewModel.Cost`. Using a converter `CostTextBlock` updates when `ViewModel.Cost` updates. When we bind to a function, Cost renders in the correct format, but does not update.
In the ViewModel we have:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    decimal? _Cost = default(decimal?);
    public decimal? Cost
    {
        get
        {
            return _Cost;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == 0) value = null;
            Set(ref _Cost, value);
        }
    }
```

Elsewhere in the ViewModel we update Cost:

```
this.Cost = null;
```

In App.xaml we define the converter:

```
<T10Converters:StringFormatConverter x:Key="PriceConverter" Format="{}{0:N2}"/>
```

In the view:

```
Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Cost,Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource PriceConverter}}"/>
```

We can load the view with an order and Cost renders correctly. Using the converter, when Cost is set to null the change is reflected in the view.

We also have a method which does the same as the converter:

```
public static string FormatPrice(decimal? price)
{
    if (price == null)
        return null;
    return ((decimal)price).ToString("N2");
}
```

In which case the xaml in the view is

```
Text="{x:Bind Helpers:Globalisation.FormatPrice(ViewModel.Cost),Mode=OneWay}"
```

This correctly formats Cost in the view, but the same code used with the converter `this.Cost = null;` does not update the view even though Cost is updated.

Why is it that `CostTextBlock` does not reflect updates to `ViewModel.Cost` when it is bound to `FormatPrice`?

Comment: Does it mean that it doesn't work only when cost is *null*? What should happen/be shown when cost is *null*? Shouldn't be the string empty when cost is null?

Comment: @Romasz When Cost is null the view should show blank Cost. This is the case when we use the converter. When I bind the control to FormatPrice, Cost is not updated in the view. If I change FormatPrice to return String.Empty, it makes no difference. Cost still does not update in the view.

Comment: would it not be better to return 0.0 on the null case? Secondly look how the converter is implemented it might enlighten you to as the reason for the null case working with the converter vs the static method.

Comment: @mvermef  the spec requires a blank order have a blank cost. FormatPrice correctly sets the property to null. The question is why the view doesn't update.

Comment: Does the converter called when you set the ViewModel.Cost to null? `x:Bind` not really like the null values.

Comment: @Tóth Tibor the converter is happy with x:Bind and null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurred in a few properties which were updated from the viewmodel. I managed to work around this issue using `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(<property>));`

`ViewModelBase` is meant to handle change notification and it seems to do so in all cases where controls are bound to properties. If anyone can come up with a better solution or an explanation of why change notification isn't firing in these few cases where controls are bound to functions, I'll happily mark them as answer.

Comment: Do you do some transformation in the setters like in your example `if (value == 0) value = null;`? Just because the `Set` method only fires `PropertyChanged` if the field and the value are not equals.

Comment: That's correct @Tóth Tibor.if (value != _Cost)
{
    if (value == 0)
        value = null;